# What's the best strategy for updating an Jhipster application?

Tags: jhipster

JHipster helps to quickly set up a web application. The upgrading process however doesn't go so smoothly.

I created a [Jhipster application](https://github.com/assimbly/gateway), starting with version 4. The first time, I upgraded from version 4 to 5 I used the [automatic update procedure](https://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/). The JHipster website states:

"When a new version of JHipster is released, the JHipster upgrade sub-generator helps upgrading an existing application to this new version, without erasing your changes."

However, I got 1000+ errors after upgrade that I needed to resolve. When upgrading from version 5 to 6 this happened as well. I then created a JHipster application from scratch and applied my custom code manually, instead of using the automatic upgrade.

Recently I read, when you have a lot of custom code, it's better to not use Jhipster anymore and upgrade several dependencies yourself.

Now, version 7 came out. I like to consider an upgrading strategy that considers:

- The least developing/debugging effort.
- Keep custom code intact.
- Take advantage of the latest JHipster features when possible.

What is the best upgrade strategy to follow?

1. Automatic upgrade and resolve errors
2. Create new JHipster with the latest version and apply custom code
3. Update dependencies manually without using JHipster (using only Gradle and NPM)

Comment: Considering that your application has been developed for at least 2 years, is there any reason why you want to upgrade the generator? Your custom code is the value of your app. Personally, I would have cut off all dependencies from JHipster long time ago (3 months after project start) and manage my app as a spring boot application without any dependency on JHipster.

Comment: I always thought of Jhipster as a tool/framework to not only generate, but also keeping my application up to date. Though, the reasons aren't very strict, the thoughts behind it:

1. Focus on creating business value, instead of technology/frameworks (and let Jhipster do this for me).
2. Get the latest JHipster features in an existing application
3. Get the latest bug fixes and security updates
4. Get the latest best practices from the Jhipster community
5. Update multiple dependencies at once and ensure they work together.
6. Keep using the generator for example creating new entities.

Comment: For me, your approach can work only for simple applications like prototypes or student's projects, it can't work for applications with rich business logic and focused user experience. JHipster does not separate enough the business logic from framework code and the generated UI is basic.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with option 3 then. I do think that the JHipster website could be clearer on this point.